# Виджет меняет форму при смене фонового цвета

Tags: android, android-widgets

Пишу виджет на рабочий стол, состоящий из одного TextView с текстом (API 16+).
Создаю shape.xml для скругления углов TextView-а.
На экране все красиво получается. Далее в настройках виджета нужно менять цвет фона.
Я делаю remoteViews.setInt( R.id.layout, "setBackgroundColor", color).
Цвет меняется, но виджет становится прямоугольным, без скругления углов.
Почему это происходит? Куда девается заданная форма?

Как же тогда менять цвет виджета, если он жестко прописан в xml шейпа?

Comment: это происходит из за того, что сначала вы назначаете бэкграундом свой кастомный шейп, а потом подменяете бэкграунд на просто цвет - он становится бэкграундом вашего виджета **вместо** шейпа, а вид виджета при этом используется стандартный.

Comment: Спс. То есть менять динамически цвет невозможно при условии сохранения шейпа? Или как-то можно? Вариант создать несколько шейпов с разными цветами не особо устраивает.

Comment: Нужно менять цвет самого шейпа, но я с виджетами мало работал и ничего конкретного подсказать не могу. Вообще для этого есть Tint или [еще варианты](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164630/how-to-change-shape-color-dynamically), но это для виджетов на разметке.

Comment: Так цвет шейпа прописан в xml. Как его поменять программно?

Comment: xml всего лишь форма описания объекта. Вы можете создать объект через xml и потом обращаться к нему программно (после инфлейта xml-описание объекта превращается в полноценный объект, к которому можно обратиться из кода), меняя любые свойства, только с виджетами на экране это сложнее, так как прямого доступа к их объектам нет